# Nvidia X server settings reverts backs on startup\wakeup\login

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, nvidia-settings

I'm using the nvidia-driver-450 on ubuntu 20 with a 3 screen setup, 2 horizontal 27" 1 vertical 24" screen. each time a session begins the settings for the vertical screen reverts back to horizontal as well as other changes I tried like reverting to 16:9 when it was set to 16:10.

the changes are saved to the xorg.conf

any ideas?

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.82

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 450.57

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung S27H65x"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce RTX 2070"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-5"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +3000+124 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}, DP-4: nvidia-auto-select +1080+124 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=right, ForceCompositionPipeline=On, AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: set the monitor settings the way you want and just do the following command sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml restart and report back..

Comment: I think it worked
thank you very much i was looking for a long time to find a way to fix it. 
what did i just do?

Comment: using multiple monitors on Ubuntu is sometimes a problem, cause gdm does not recognize them properly and the solution is just to copy the monitors.xml which has the settings for all the monitors into the directory .config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple by copying the file **monitors.xml** into the directory **~gdm/.config/monitors.xml** using the command:

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
```